# Trouble with Laravel's dot notation when using sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.1

I'm having a slight problem when trying to store and grab items from the session.  I'm using an API and I am attempting to cache the results of this api into the session.

The problem is the API often returns domain names which I am trying to cache, `google.com` for example and then a value for that domain.

Unfortunately, when I store this using `Session::put($domain, $value)` and then return `Session::all()`, the array looks like the following...

```
array(
    'google' => 
        'com' => 'my_value'
)
```

I really need it to be...

```
array(
    'google.com' => 'my_value'
)
```

As you can see, the dot notation is destroying the integrity of the array depending.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried escaping the period? What happens if you try `google\.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at Laravel code, you won't be able to solve it easily. Laravel uses here `Arr::set` method which uses dot notation to create multi dimensional array.

You should consider replacing `.` into for example `_` so instead `google.com` use `google_com` as your session key.

Comment: @user3158900 After rethinking I think it should be possible out of the box without using strange changes on user side. I've added pull request for that - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/11332

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  For now it looks like using `str_replace` is the thing to do.

Comment: You're welcome, unfortunately my pull hasn't been merged